# Using Location Manager when app is removed from background in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, geolocation, core-location

I am developing one app, i would like to know about location manager that will it work when user remove the app from background in iOS 7 and above?

I am using this delegate method: 
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;

Will it get called when the app is removed from background?

The distance filter i have set is 50 meters with desiredAccuracy of NearestHundredMeters.

Regards,
Aamir

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run your app when app is removed from background, you have to follow some instruction which are in this document.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: I am not using region monitoring since it requires cellular data & it has limitation of monitoring only 20 regions.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like a function to run in background simply go to AppDelegate and place your code block in the "applicationDidEnterBackground" function [AppDelegate Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkIff.png)